# How do I view hidden folders with Solid Explorer?

Tags: file-management, hidden

It's easy to create hidden folders/files by starting their name with a dot (e.g, ".nomedia"). Once created, how do I view/delete them using Solid Explorer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Tap the three dots in the top right of the app
2. Choose 'Folder options'

[image: Folder options menu]

3. Ensure 'Show hidden files' is ticked (option is unchecked in screenshot below)

[image: Show hidden files option]

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. (And with helpful illustrations to boot.)